# How to show that if $\sum_na_n=\infty$ and $a_n\downarrow 0$ then $\sum\limits_n\min(a_{n},\frac{1}{n})=\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n\downarrow 0, \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=+\infty,   b_n=\min\{a_n,1/n\}$. Prove that $\sum b_n $ diverges.

In fact, I have known that two positive divergent series $\sum a_n ~\sum b_n$,  $c_n=\min\{a_n,b_n\}, \sum c_n$ is not always divergent.
But I do not know why this above series is surely divergent. Sincerely thanks.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/757549/9464

Comment: Another duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/739975/9464

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Use [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ convergent,if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^na_{2^n}$ convergent

so we only show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\min\left(a_{2^n},\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)$$ divergent

if some postive integer $n$ such $a_{2^n}\ge\dfrac{1}{2^n}$,then $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\min\left(a_{2^n},\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}1$$ divergent

if some postive integer $n$ such $a_{2^n}<\dfrac{1}{2^n}$,then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^n\min\left(a_{2^n},\dfrac{1}{2^n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^na_{2^n}$$ is divergent,because  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}$ divergent,then you can  use Cauchy condensation test

Comment: why download? can you explain?

Comment: if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n},a_{n}>0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n},b_{n}>0$ divergent, then $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty}(a_{n}+b_{n})$ divergent

Comment: you can part two set $A=\{a_{n}|a_{2^n}\le \dfrac{1}{2^n}\},B=\{a_{n}|a_{2^n}>\dfrac{1}{2^n}\}$,then  you can consider $A\bigcup B$

Comment: The condensation test only holds for non-increasing sequences.  While $1/n$ is nonincreasing, we only know that $a_n$ approaches zero, and it is easy to construct a sequence (e.g., $a_n=0$ if $n$ is odd and $2/n$ otherwise) such that $\min(a_n,1/n)$ is not non-increasing.

Comment: @Aaron: the notation $a_n \downarrow 0$ means that $a_n$ *decreases* to $0$. If this was your only objection, you might want to reconsider your vote.

Comment: @AlexM. I didn't vote.

Comment: Even with the above clarification, @Aaron's question still stands: how do you know that $\min \{ a_n , \frac 1 n \}$ decreases? (I don't suggest that it isn't, I only ask why it should be so.)

Comment: Indeed, you should add a line mentioning (i) that the test requires non-increasing sequence, and (ii) justifying that the sequence is indeed non-increasing (it is not hard, but it's necessary).

Answer (score 2):

Suppose instead that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ converges.$\;$  Then $\displaystyle b_n\downarrow0\;$ (since $a_n\downarrow 0$ and $\frac{1}{n}\downarrow0$),

so $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}nb_n=0$  (as in the links shown below);

so $b_n=a_n$ for $n\ge N$ (for some $N\in\mathbb{N}$) and therefore $\displaystyle\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}b_n=\displaystyle\sum_{n=N}^{\infty}a_n$ diverges.

This gives a contradiction, so $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n$ diverges.

Comment: How do you obtain $\lim \limits _{n \to \infty} n b_n = 0$? If $a_n = \frac 1 {n+1}$, then $b_n = \min \{ \frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1 n \} =  \frac 1 {n+1}$ so your conclusion seems not to hold.

Comment: @AlexM. I am using the result of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369669

Comment: @user84413 That should be including in the answer, not a comment (with justification as of why you can use the result; i.e., why $(b_n)_n$ is non-increasing).

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4603